# How to have margin on extended page tablix with SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

I am using Visual Studio 2010 to create some SSRS reports.

When my tablix too wide to be printed on one page, it is automatically extended on page2, the problem is that i have a left margin on page1 which is not applied on extended page2.

Then when printed, the printer will cut the first tablix column of the page2, since it is not included in its print zone.

Do you have any idea how to force margin with extended tablix ?

(Here an example of an extended tablix with margin on p1 but not on extended page)

[image]

Comment: What are the margin setting of the report

Comment: 0.5in left and 0.5in right

Comment: are you seeing this behavior when you are printing directly from ssrs/ report viewer or is this behavior present when you are exporting to pdf?

Comment: When I click on Print layout, so both export and print are like that

Comment: I think the problem is that you created a **"margin"** inside the report with whitespace between the edge of the report and the start of your table instead of using the margin properties. When the report spills to the next page, it uses the .5 in page margin but doesn't replicate the whitespace. You should move the table left to the edge of the report and increase the margin in the report properties.

Comment: This question on [SSRS - Space / Margin between header and tablix in content area on subsequent page](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36709703/1366033) is about vertical spacing, but the discussion might helpful.