# SSRS - Space / Margin between header and tablix in content area on subsequent page

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, crystal-reports, ssrs-2008

Okay, I know that the question is hard to digest.

So I hope this attached picture will make more sense of my question.

Basically I want to maintain some space between my header and my tablix after first page.

I use bottom border for my header and user don't want to see the table and the header just glued together.

tried to put empty textbox (hidden) but not really working as I can't repeat the textbox on subsequent page.

[image]

Comment: do you have ConsumeContainerWhiteSpace property set to true? what is the value of location property of your tablix?

Comment: @PratikKaje yup, set the consumeContainerWhiteSpace set to true (i believe this property is more of avoiding extra blank soace at the end of report); location of tablix, left 0.2cm top 1.xx cm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though you have a gap between the top of the Report Body section and the top of your tablix - this would lead to an extra gap on the first page, which is not repeated on subsequent pages.

If you move your tablix so that there is no gap between it and the top of the Report Body section, this should resolve the problem.

Comment: Hi mark, you lost me at flush; yes on the firs page i space those you manually (dragging the tablix where i see fit)

Comment: @NahwinRajan: I've rephrased my answer to remove the word "flush" - I hope this is clearer.

Comment: Hi mark, will give it a try tomorrow back in the office but do you understand why ? And what if i have couple text box before tablix only on first page ?

Comment: @NahwinRajan: Everything in the Page Header section is supposed to appear on every page; everything in the Report Body section is only supposed to appear once (in the order specified). So the header and the gap under it in the Page Header are repeated on every page, while the gap between the top of the Report Body section and the tablix is shown the first time the tablix appears. If the tablix has enough data to be continued on a second page, the gap in the Report Body section is not repeated. Similarly, text boxes above the tablix in the Report Body section will appear on the first page only.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, tried it and didn't work out, I end up not using borderline and instead used normal line where I can put it slightly above the bottom part of header which will give a bit of gap between header and tablix,  thank you very much for your help mark!! 

Answer (score 0):

Mark Bannister's answer is correct.  Your pictures incorrectly place space between the header and content - tablix.  The header shares a border the content - tablix not the body.

The solution, is to place an empty header in your report and that will create the space between the top of the page and the content - tablix you need.

[image: Picture 1 Wherein we see the first page]

[image: Picture 2 wherein we see the answer which is to use the header to create space]